# How to search for values in a file/array in php and return everything after the found value

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have an .ini file which looks like:

```
password = password123
username = username123
host = host123
```

In my php I want to save the value "password123" to a private member variable called $password, and the same with "username123" and "host123" to private member variables. The prefixed values (password = , username = ,host = ) will never change but the values after may be subject to change. I tried saving the file to an array and searching it but had some problems.. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function:

```
class Foobar {
    private $password, $username, $host;

    public function __construct($filename) {
        $array = parse_ini_file($filename);

        $this->password = $array['password'];
        $this->username = $array['username'];
        $this->host = $array['host'];
    }
}
```